# imacros work in offline mode

Tags: javascript, imacros

I want a command to work offline in imacro for firefox
Is there any way to emaulate manually clicking file->work offline.

even if there is some javascript command or someway to do it by vb code it is ok.

basically what i am trying to achieve is that i open a page which has a form. now i fill the form with some values and click submit and extract results from the next page. again i open the 1st page with the form. now i want to do this opening of the 1st page in offline mode so that it is faster as teh page is already there in cache. next again i need to go online before i click submit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the following Code works for iMacros on Firefox to toggle 'Work Offline' ON/OFF:

> ```
> EVENT TYPE=KEYPRESS SELECTOR=* Char="f" MODIFIERS="alt"
> EVENT TYPE=KEYPRESS SELECTOR=* Char="k" MODIFIERS="alt"
> ```